# Why is sort giving me random sorting (Knockout observable array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, knockout.js

I have an observable array which contains numbers. I want to sort with a button on price. This is my viewmodel:

```
var ViewModel = function(model) {
        self.Numbers = ko.observableArray(model);
        self.SortArray = function() {

            InstanceViewModel.Numbers.sort(function (left, right) {
                return left.id == right.id ? 0 : (left.id < right.id ? -1 : 1) })
        }
    }

    var InstanceViewModel = new ViewModel([{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"}]);

    ko.applyBindings(InstanceViewModel);
```

This is my html:

```
<input type="button" value="Sort" data-bind="click: SortArrayNum">
    <div data-bind="foreach: Numbers">
        <h1 data-bind="text: id"></h1>
    </div>
```

Its not sorting properly how is this possible? It says also: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined". I got this to work a time ago and it was sorting randomly strange. What am i doing wrong guys?

Comment: Seems picky, but it's actually important: you do *not* have an array of numbers. You have an array of objects that have a property "id" that contains a string (which conicidentally contains a numeric value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="Sort" data-bind="click: SortArray">

    <div data-bind="foreach: Numbers">
        <h1 data-bind="text: id"></h1>
    </div>


var ViewModel = function(model) {
        self.Numbers = ko.observableArray(model);
        self.SortArray = function() {

          self.Numbers.sort(function (left, right) {
                return left.id == right.id ? 0 : (left.id < right.id ? -1 : 1) })
        }
    }

    var InstanceViewModel = new ViewModel([{"id":"2"},{"id":"1"},{"id":"6"},{"id":"4"}]);

    ko.applyBindings(InstanceViewModel);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/93Z8N/239/

You are getting exception because your function is called SortArray not SortArrayNum

Answer (score 2):

by reading http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html the correct way is

```
myObservableArray.sort(function (left, right) { return left.lastName == right.lastName ? 0 : (left.lastName < right.lastName ? -1 : 1) })
```

therefore, shouldn't it be

```
self.SortArray = function () { 
   return self.Numbers.sort(function (left, right) { return left.id == right.id ? 0 : (left.id < right.id ? -1 : 1) }) 
}
```

instead of

```
self.SortArray = function() {

            InstanceViewModel.Numbers.sort(function (left, right) {
                return left.id == right.id ? 0 : (left.id < right.id ? -1 : 1) })
        }
```